# Store 2 edit texts and display it in the next activity

Tags: android

i am have an input on two edit texts, the values get stored from these two edit texts and than displayed in the next activity in two different textViews. The problem i am having is on the output side, both the textviews display the same Text, whereas the input value is different for both the edit texts.

Here is my code.

```
  public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.logcatdev.lovescanner.MESSAGE";   
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.logcatdev.lovescanner.MESSAGE";    


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.names);

    final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {


            // Do something in response to button
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scan.class);
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);


            Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scan.class);

            //get the value of the editText, convert it to string and store it in a string variable

            EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();


        intent2.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message2);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

NEXT ACTIVITY

```
Intent intent = getIntent();


Intent intent2 = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Names.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String message2 = intent2.getStringExtra(Names.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);

    //set the value of message to the textview
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(message);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    textView1.setText(message2);
```

where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change your key for different values like this

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.logcatdev.lovescanner.MESSAGE1";   
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.logcatdev.lovescanner.MESSAGE2";
```

Then update your onClickListener to this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scan.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, editText1.getText().toString());
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, editText2.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

In your next activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message1 = intent.getStringExtra(Names.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(Names.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);

TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView1.setText(message1);

TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
textView2.setText(message2);
```

Comment: This should work. Intent extras are key-value pairs so you need two different keys, these are the string values. If they are equal, the second `putExtra` will override the first.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating two different intents. You only need one intent to start a second activity, and then you can put multiple String extras. So in your first activity just do

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scan.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
String message = editText.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);


EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, message2);
```

And you can retrieve them in your second activity with

```
String message = intent.getStringExtra(Names.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(Names.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
```

Comment: Tried but still the same result

Comment: Like Médéric said in his answer, you need `EXTRA_MESSAGE` and `EXTRA_MESSAGE2` to be different strings.

Answer (score 0):

I have made changes in java code for first activity

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.logcatdev.lovescanner.MESSAGE";   
        public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.logcatdev.lovescanner.MESSAGE";    


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.names);

        final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);



        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


                // Do something in response to button
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Scan.class);
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String message = editText.getText().toString();
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

                //get the value of the editText, convert it to string and store it in a string variable

                EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();


            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, message2);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

You have to send different string key when you are sending different message.
Use this code it will help you!!

Comment: Can you post both full source code of both activities. The logic is correct, it should be implementation error. Intent does work as I post.